# radio group functionality

Tags: asp.net

On my ASPxGrid, I have two columns: Approve and Deny. Both the columns are of boolean type (Radio buttons).

In a particular row, if a user selects the radio button for the Approve column then the radio button for the Deny column should be unselected and vice versa.

I also have a header radio button for each  of these columns. If the header radio button is selected, then the corresponding radio buttons from that column should be selected and all the radio buttons from the other columns should be unselected.

I am dynamically creating these radio buttons for each column.

```
<DataItemTemplate>
    <dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="chkAppDataItem" runat="server">
    </dx:ASPxRadioButton>
</DataItemTemplate>

<HeaderCaptionTemplate>
      <dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="chkAppHeader" runat="server">
      </dx:ASPxRadioButton>
</HeaderCaptionTemplate>
```

Can I achieve this functionality with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The buttons are grouped logically if
>   they all share the same GroupName
>   property.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxRadioButtontopic

This will at least solve the first part of your problem.